# getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity: "These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have set up a Cognito Identity Pool with a custom developer provider name "my.developer".  From my Node Lambda function I call the following code:

```
AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-1:*****'  // I am using a valid UUID here
});
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

var params = {
    IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-1:*****',
    Logins: { 'my.developer': 'test-user' }
};
cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params,
    function(err, data) {
        console.log('error:', err);
        console.log('data:', data);
    }
);
```

...when I test the function I get an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource",
  "errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:43:27)",
```

I have Cognito_Unauth_Role and Cognito_Auth_Role which both resemble:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "cognito-identity:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

...what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the execution role of your Lambda function (This is **not** Cognito_Unauth_Role, nor Cognito_Auth_Role, but the role that your Lambda function uses while it is executing) has the sufficient permissions for Cognito service. An example policy would be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "cognito-identity:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, removing the following lines fixed the problem:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-1:*****'  // I am using a valid UUID here
});
```

...I guess that by creating the CognitoIdentityCredentials object within the lambda function it has removed the roles configured within the web console.

Answer (score -1):

The error message:

> "errorMessage": "These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource"

means that these credentials here should be the ones for developer access. So it should be Basic Credentials with `access key` and `secret key`.

Comment: Hi,I think this is an answer to the original question that was "These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource”. To my mind, no other post but mine is an answer to this original question.